# Generate discrete distributions with same mean and variance

Tags: distributions, variance, mean

I have a question concerning mean-variance analysis. I need to compute 2 discrete distributions with equal mean and variance. One should be a distribution taking values x and y and the other one taking values z, 0, and y. 
The values should take the following form:
Distribution 1: prob(x)=3/10; prob(y)=7/10
Distribution 2: Prob(y)=7/10; prob(0)=unknown; prob(z)=unknown
The idea is to chose y,z,x, to generate equal mean and variance in both distributions. I'm not an expert so I don't know if there are two many unknowns or if this is possible at all. 
I would be very greatful for hints how to solve this.

Comment: There are some troubling inconsistencies in your statement. First, your distributions appear to be *univariate* rather than "bivariate."  Are you perhaps using "bivariate" in the sense of "takes on two distinct values"? Second, what do you mean by "no difference in skewness"?  Third, does your notation to specify distributions perhaps mean that in distribution 1 the chance of $x$ is $6/10$ and the chance of $y$ is $4/10$, whereas in distribution 2 the chance of $x$ is $6/10$, of $0$ is $3/10$, and of $z$ is $1/10$? Do you intend for the chances of $x$ to be the same in both distributions?

Comment: What does "no difference in skewness on the right side" mean?

Comment: You are right, there were many inconsistencies. I updated the questions. thank you for your comments.